# How to print out array from class object, initialized in constructor

Tags: c#, indexer

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntIndexer myIntIndexer = new IntIndexer(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myIntIndexer[i]);
        }
    }
}
class IntIndexer
{
    private string[] myData;

    public IntIndexer(int size)
    {
        myData = new string[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter an antry");
            myData[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile I get an error cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type IntIndexer What is wrong with my code? This error comes from `Console.WriteLine(myIntIndexer[i]);`

Comment: Your problem is here `Console.WriteLine(myIntIndexer[i])`. Your variable is not a container

Comment: Your `IntIndexer` class hasn't indexer. Refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) article for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Your type `IntIndexer` is a class but you attempt to access it as an array of your class via the statement `myIntIndexer[i]`. You'd have to expose the string in the class and access that instead, since it seems that you want to access the `string` as an array of characters:

```
public string[] myData;
```

and

```
Console.WriteLine(myIntIndexer.myData[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
Console.WriteLine(myIntIndexer[i]);
```

You are trying to use an index on your instance of `IntIndexer` as if the instance were an array itself, but the class only *contains* an array as a private field.  You need to expose this somehow, and one way to do that is to create a property with an accessor:

```
public string[] MyData
{
    get { return myData; }
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(myIntIndexer.MyData[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing your instance like an array, you can expose the array like the other answers mentioned or provide an indexer property to access the content of the array

```
 public string this[int index]
 {
     get
     {
          return myData[i];
     } 
 }
```

This will give you the ability to index into your instance like you are currently doing in your answer